# Adding Some Extra calculation during the time of Sum on mongodb $sum function

Tags: mongodb

My Mongo-Db dataset is this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a267533754884223467604a"),
    "user_id" : "5a20ee1acdacc7086ce7742c",
    "tv_count" : 1,
    "ac_count" : 0,
    "fridge_count" : 0,
    "blower_count" : 0,
    "chair_count" : 0,
    "sofa_count" : 0,
    "D2H_count" : 2,
    "lastmodified" : ISODate("2017-12-05T10:30:30.559Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

So I know i want to do some modification during the time of Sum.
My Sum Code is this:

```
Accessories.aggregate([
                {$match: { "lastmodified":{$gt: newTime}}},
                { 
                    $project: {
                        total: { 
                            $add: [ "$tv_count", "$ac_count", "$fridge_count", "$blower_count", "$chair_count", "$sofa_count", "$D2H_count"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]);
```

So it will return the result

```
[ { _id: 5a267533754884223467604a, total: 3 } ]
```

Now I want to do some extra calculation. Example is

```
Earlier Result will be 1+0+0+0+0+0+2 = 3

My desire result will be like (1*2)+0+0+0+0+0+(2*4) = 10
```

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: This one is done easily if value will be like $add: [(1*2)+0+0+0+0+0+(2*4)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply include additional nested calculations inside your existing projection like so:

```
$project: {
    total: { 
        $add: [ { $multiply: [ "$tv_count", 2 ] }, "$ac_count", "$fridge_count", "$blower_count", "$chair_count", "$sofa_count", { $multiply: [ "$D2H_count", 4 ] }]
    }
}
```

You should **not** use the `$addFields` or any other additional stage for this type of thing, really, since adding stages will slow down the aggregation pipeline and adding fields in particular will inflate the interim result documents between the stages so again slow down your query.

Comment: You Simply Pick the Earlier Answer Concept but In a very Precise  Manner.

Comment: Anyways Thanks a lot @dnickless

Comment: Really Appreciate

Answer (score 0):

I would add an `$addFields` stage in the aggregation pipeline between the `$match` and the `@project` stage.
In the `$addFields` stage you can define new "helper fields" - eg.

```
{ $addFields: {
    "tv_temp": { $multiply: [ "$tv_count", 2 ] },
    "D2H_temp": { $multiply: [ "$D2H_count", 4 ] },
  }
}
```

Using these fields, you can now calculate the total:

```
{ $project: {
  total: { 
    $add: [ "$tv_temp", "$ac_count", "$fridge_count", "$blower_count", "$chair_count", "$sofa_count", "$D2H_temp"]
  }
}}
```

Comment: Thanks @peter berggreen for your support.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :-)